# Adding pure class as External JAR

Tags: android, jar, external

I have a class with common definitions for the client and the server. I would like to let every client developer use these definitions by sending over this class as a JAR file. Previously I have exported the class file to a JAR and created a new client that used this JAR as external JAR (in the build path). Recently I tried building a new version of this JAR but I get in the client an error stating " cannot be resolved to a type".

Simon

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include this jar into your Android project, then you just do the following steps in your Eclipse environment.

1. Right click on your project in the project's panel.
2. Select “Properties” option.
3. In the Properties window, Click on “Java Build Path”.
4. In the right side of that window, select “Libraries” tab.
5. Click on “Add External JARs” button and add this library where you have saved previously.
6. Now click on “Order and Export” tab and check on “JarName.jar”
7. Click on “Ok”.

Comment: What is "MDWrapper.jar"? I cannot see such a JAR in "Order and Export".

Comment: sorry replace it with your jar name